# React - fetch 'message' from Meta-Data element of the response from an Ajax post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

So I have received this response from an Ajax post request (part of the response is shown) where:

```
Data:
  Meta-Data:
    Topic : "Sign-Up"
    Message : "Already in the System!"
    Response Code : "650"
.
.
.
```

how can I fetch the message and show it to user? I was thinking I could do this in React:

```
    state = {
    username : "John",
    password : "somePass",
    postResponse : null
    }
    axios.post(URL, JSON.stringify({ username : this.state.username , password: this.state.password})
    .then(response => { this.setState({postResponse : response.data}) }
```

and then in render() I do:

```
     render(){
let message = null; 
    if (this.state.postResponse){
    message = <p>{this.postResponse.data.meta-data.message}</p> //apparently the dash is breaking the code!
    }
     return(<div> {message} </div>)}
```

Which doesn't work at all!
"it is a part of my code, I hope I've included all necessary parts"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I can see. You had this.postResponse. It should be this.state.postResponse from what I can tell. Also, you need to put “meta-data” into quotes and use brackets to reference it, as shown below.

```
state = {
    username : "John",
    password : "somePass",
    postResponse : null
    }
    axios.post(URL, JSON.stringify({ username : this.state.username , password: this.state.password})
    .then(response => { this.setState({postResponse : response.data}) }

render(){
  let message = null; 
  if (this.state.postResponse){
    message = <p>{this.state.postResponse[“meta-data”].message}</p>
    }
     return(<div> {message} </div>)}
```

Comment: Thank you. I also didn't know I could ask the backend programmer to change Meta-Data to MetaData to make the work simpler, but I just figured it out.

Comment: Yea - good idea. It makes things a lot easier. Also, I’m not sure if it matters much to you or not, but I noticed if you were going to reference metaData directly from the axios response, it would be response.data.data.metaData. If it’s easy to change, it may be worth using another key instead of data - such as “body” - to avoid confusion (i.e. response.data.body.metaData).